# how to use functions in the main servlet function

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, backend

I am working on a web application using java and I need to use external function in the main servlet function, they are in the same file I don't know how.
I will use the function multiple times so what should I do?

for example assume that my servlet is like this
I want to execute say() inside main servlet function processRequest() and I tried this.say() and calling an object from servlet class

```
public void say(){
        System.out.println("say called <br>");
    }

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Inventory Control</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        say();
        this.say();
        InventoryController inven =new InventoryController();
        inven.say();
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn a little about java packages, imports and method calls.  ??

Comment: What do you mean by "external function" ? try to put your code to clarify the question